# Will increasing the # of rounds in bcrypt make it good enough for encrypting strings?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, bcrypt, sha

Looking through the various encrypting and hashing algorithms they seem to focus on computation time vs security, and seem to target encrypting/hashing passwords.

In my scenario I am trying to encrypt a string that will be provided to the enduser, of which later I will provided the unencrypted version that they can match up to the encrypted version to verify a certain action (a la a provably fair system)

I thought of using sha-512, providing the hash and then later on providing the unecrypted string for which the enduser will be able to match up the hash and the unencrypted string.

However I recently discoved bcrypt, for which certain people have said it is a better choice. Now for me it does not matter how long it takes to generate the hash so for my circumstances is it best to use bcrypt with an ungodly # of rounds to make my string harder to crack or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords It´s not wrong, proceed.

Comment: If you are encrypting your string with a random 128-bit key, then there is no way it could be bruteforced; you don't need to add extra rounds or compuatational work. Give them the AES-128 encrypted string, and the SHA-256 of the unencrypted string. Later simply give them the key. You're unclear what threat you're trying to defend against.